# How to set comments to all SQL queries generated from Spring Data JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

We're using Spring Data JPA repository. Our requirement is to set comments to all queries generated to identify them uniquely. for e.g:  select * from AccountMTable;/** Nonce: 1234ersgsr123 AND service: api**/

AccountMappingRepository Interface

```
public interface AccountMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountMappingRecord, Long> {

  List<AccountMappingRecord> findByBusCustId(long busCustId);
}
```

AccountMapping

```
@Setter
@Table(name = "account_mapping")
@Entity
public class AccountMappingRecord implements DomainEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column
  private long id;
```

I want to set comments to queries generated by above repository(there are many such repository interfaces in application) for CRUD operations.
Please help me in setting unique comments to every query generated.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Comment: @ZackMacomber my query is about adding comment to sql queries generated through Spring Data JPA framework. My requirement is - We have multiple repositories I want to understand way to instrument query object and set comments to it at common place.

Comment: @ShashiKanthThummanapalli  did you find the solution , even i wanted to try the same